# gradle hook before dependency retrieve

Tags: gradle, dependencies, authorization

I have all of my dependencies located in password protected repository.

I have a function which asks for username and password but it's bother me to frequently.

Is there a way to execute it right before dependency retrieve?
In most of the cases I have all dependencies in my local maven/gradle cache as I'm using exact versions.

Having password in ~/build.properties in plain text is not secure so I would prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.timroes.de/2014/01/19/using-password-prompts-with-gradle-build-files/

I find this one it's some kind of workaround to have a special build + resolve task

if someone has a better idea you are welcome.